# Visual Studio 2015 Extension - How to get workspace of current Solution

Tags: visual-studio

I am developing an extension to Visual Studio 2015. How do I get workspace object for the current solution loaded in the IDE so that my extension can work on it?

A lot of samples seem to load a project or a solution as below, however, I want to get the workspace of the Solution loaded in the IDE so that my extension can access to it.

```
Dim workspace = New AdhocWorkspace()
Dim solution  = workspace.CurrentSolution
Dim project   = solution.AddProject("projectName", "assemblyName", LanguageNames.VisualBasic)
Dim document = project.AddDocument("name.vb", "...some code")
```

Answer (score 3):

Roslyn defines several types of workspaces but the one you are interested in is a VisualStudioWorkspace.

You can get to it via MEF from the constructor of your vsix:

```
[ImportingConstructor]
public Ctor([Import(typeof(SVsServiceProvider), AllowDefault = true)] IServiceProvider vsServiceProvider, [Import(typeof(VisualStudioWorkspace), AllowDefault = true)] Workspace vsWorkspace)
```

Or by using the Component Service:

```
IComponentModel componentModel = this.serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(SComponentModel)) as IComponentModel;
var workspace = componentModel.GetService<Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.VisualStudioWorkspace>();
```

You may find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24200125/how-to-get-workspace-from-visualstudioworkspace) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23578399/how-to-get-reference-to-roslyn-workspace-object-from-ivssolution) useful as well.

Comment: What is the best method of adding required references for this solution to a VSIX project and what references do I need?

If you could provide VB.NET version of the suggestion solution it would save a lot of time!

Comment: I am not familiar with VB.NET

Comment: You have to add a reference to Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentModelHost assembly for IComponentModel (via Add Reference -> Assemblies -> Extensions), and to Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices assembly for VisualStudioWorkspace (via nuget).

Comment: Why in first case you use ```IServiceProvider ``` but in second case you use ```SComponentModel```?